# Sticking div to the bottom of screen

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a div to be sticked at bottom of the page until the user scroll's down to his original location. In other words, I want a div to stick to the bottom of screen, until the user scroll's to the location where it is applied on the page.

I have used the following code and it works fine. But it fluctuates when it is applied to the original location.

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight>= $(document).height() - 150)
        {
            var cls = $('#StickyFooter').attr('class');
            if (cls != "footer NonStickyFooter") {
                $('#StickyFooter').removeClass('StickyFooter').addClass('NonStickyFooter');
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        else {

            $('#StickyFooter').removeClass('NonStickyFooter').addClass('StickyFooter');
            $(window).bind('scroll');
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: you can pass the css of position fixed for  div

Comment: share your complete code